# Database Table Design for read only values

Tags: database, binary, normalization

Database Design:

I have two values as Tsunami_Indicators:

1. Early Warning
2. Late Warning

Based on these two values there are a number of Tsunami_Rescue_Activities such as:

```
Early Warning------Build Wall 
Early Warning------Release dock ships
Early Warning------Alert fishermen
Early Warning-----etc.

Late Warning-------Provide radioactive foolproof masks
Late Warning-------Evacuate coastline
Late Warning-------Deploy airforce
Late Warning-------etc.
```

So should I keep the two values of Tsunami_Indicators as a drop down list in the Tsunami_Rescue_Activities table or create a separate table as Tsunami_Indicators?

I feel create a separate table Tsunami_Indicators for Late Warning and Early Warning and keep their reference id in the table Tsunami_Rescue_Activities.

But then have a doubt if for these two read only values is making a table worthy trade off?

Please advise.

Rules of normalization says " Never to have a list for any column in a tuple", but the doubt is "Are there exceptions to this rule?"

Comment: I am a bit confused about **"drop down lists"** in a database context. what type of database are you using?

Comment: @luksch It's an Oracle DB and on the application side we are using Hibernate ORM

Comment: @luksch:Rules of normalization says " Never to have a list for any column in a tuple", but the doubt is "Are there exceptions to this rule?"

Comment: I would keep all Tsunami_Rescue_Activities in one table and have the Tsunami_Indicator a column of that table - so the table design is something like : ```CREATE TABLE Tsunami_Rescue_Activities (id int, Tsunami_Indicator int, Activity varchar(500));```. I am still amazed how you can have a drop down list in a non-graphical environment (db+ORM) and how you use such a concept. But then, I an not familiar with oracle, just mysql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a static *code table* (some might say *lookup table*), it is worthwhile to put it in a database and to normalize it to 3NF.  Even the most static lookup table has at least a small risk of changing.

If and when such a change happens it is much easier to handle by making a database entry than by changing code (and potentially having to redistribute the code, if it is not web-based).